# Regex for matching specific words or their combination as well as the exception word

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to check source code scripts according to such a pattern:

'DELETE' or 'FROM' or 'DELETE FROM' followed by a space followed by any word not followed by another word separated by a dot, except for the word 'DUAL'

Something like

```
'(DELETE|FROM|DELETE FROM) \w+', where \w+ != DUAL
but not
'(DELETE|FROM|DELETE FROM) \w+\.\w+'
```

Examples

| text fragment | desired result |
| --- | --- |
| begin DELETE tbl1; | DELETE tbl1 |
| select FROM tbl2) loop | FROM tbl2 |
| fnc(); DELETE FROM tbl3 where | DELETE FROM tbl3 |
| qqq DELETE DUAL; www |  |
| eee FROM DUAL rrr |  |
| ttt DELETE FROM DUAL where |  |
| yy DELETE sch1.tbl1; uuu |  |
| iii FROM sch2.tbl2 ooo |  |
| ppp DELETE FROM sch3.tbl3 aaa |  |

My guess

```
(FROM|DELETE( FROM)?) (?!DUAL)(?!\w+\.)\w+
```

matches too much by the 1st part. Is it correct in its 2nd part (after space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
\b(?>DELETE(?: FROM)?|FROM) (?!DUAL\b)\w+\b(?!\.)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?>DELETE(?: FROM)?|FROM)`  Atomic group (No backtracking) to match either DELETE with optional FROM or only FROM
- `(?!DUAL\b)` Negative lookahead to assert not the word DUAL directly to the right followed by a word boundary
- `\w+\b` Math 1+ word characters and a word boundary
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not a dot directly to the right of the current position

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3eDELETE%28%3f%3a+FROM%29%3f%7cFROM%29+%28%3f!DUAL%5cb%29%5cw%2b%5cb%28%3f!%5c.%29&i=begin+DELETE+tbl1%3b%09DELETE+tbl1%0d%0aselect+FROM+tbl2%29+loop%09FROM+tbl2%0d%0afnc%28%29%3b+DELETE+FROM+tbl3+where%09DELETE+FROM+tbl3%0d%0aqqq+DELETE+DUAL%3b+www%09%0d%0aeee+FROM+DUAL+rrr%09%0d%0attt+DELETE+FROM+DUAL+where%09%0d%0ayy+DELETE+sch1.tbl1%3b+uuu%09%0d%0aiii+FROM+sch2.tbl2+ooo%09%0d%0appp+DELETE+FROM+sch3.tbl3+aaa)

Comment: Thanks, if now I want to search '\w.\w(' but not '\w.\w.\w(' the pattern will be '\b(?<!\.)\w+\.\w+\(' ,correct?

Comment: @Ayb You mean like this `\b(?<!\.)\w+\.\w+\b(?!\.)`  https://regex101.com/r/6kqEXy/1

Comment: I wanted it with a parenthesis literally at the end :) I get the point